# How get 1 question and 4 answers from this script?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a webGL game on Unity but want to get my php correct first.

I have 2 tables questions and answers. Each question has 4 potential answers and need to pull these from my db. 
The answer table matches with the question table through `questionId`.

**Questions:**

- Should I better use a table join or should I separate them?
- Should I simply have a select statement just for the question table then a
  join table for answers and submit separately?
- Should I have created
  the answer table with 4 columns for different answers?

**Current code:**

```php
<?php

$query = ("select questiontable.questionId, questiontable.question, answertable.answerId,answertable.answer, answertable.questionId, questiontable.scoreValue
  FROM questiontable 
  inner join answertable on questiontable.questionId=answertable.questionId   ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1 ");
$result =mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  echo $row_cnt;    
  echo $row ['question'];
  echo $row ['answer'] ;
  echo $row ['answer'] ;
  echo $row ['answer'];
  echo $row ['answer'];
}
?>
```

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `braingain`.`questionTable`
 ( `questionId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `question` VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL , `scoreValue` INT NOT NULL , `subject` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`questionId`));

CREATE TABLE `braingain`.`answerTable`
 ( `answerId` INT NOT NULL  , `answer` VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL , 'questionId', isCorrect;
```

The query should pull questions and 4 associated answers into an array.

**Desired result**

The created array should look like this:

```
|         question               | answerA | answerB | answerC | answerD |
| WHICH IS THE CORRECT SPELLING? | APPLE   | APEL    | APPUL   | APPAL   |
```

Comment: Your second `CREATE TABLE` statement is not valid SQL code. Regarding your question: it depends. If you need the data in one "transaction" (like in your above code), I would use a JOIN. In most cases you don't want to have the answers visible somewhere in your HTML code, you would only show the question (and only load it without joining the answers) in the frontend and load the answers as part of a backend validation.

Comment: (1.) Should I better use a table join or should I separate them? * Generally, querying from joined tables are faster.

 (2.) Should I have created the answer table with 4 columns for different answers? * If you expect each question to have a fixed number of answers, you can just put the answers in the same table as the questions. But, if you foresee that the number of answers might differ per question, use a separate table for the answers. That new table will have one answer option per row. Thus, the questions table will have a one-to-many relationship with the answers table.

Comment: _But, if you foresee that the number of answers might differ per question..._ Also analysing data would be much easier when separating questions and answers @programmer-man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run two nested queries,

```
$output = array();
$answer_array = array('answerA','answerB','answerC','answerD');
$query = ("select * from questiontable ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1 ");
$result =mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $output['question']=$row['question'];
    $query2 = ("select * from answerTable where questionId = ". $row ['questionId'] order by answerId);
    $result2 =mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $i=0;
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $output[answer_array[$i]]=$row2['answer'];
        $i++;
    }
}
print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: for the answer array, would it be useful to put them into a variable like, $answer_array = array('answerA','answerB','answerC','answerD');
$answerA_text= 'answerA'; etc. or would that be dumb?

Comment: answerA, answerB etc  are the indices of output array having answers text and one index being the question having the question text as your desired output array.

Comment: Cheers! this worked a treat. i just need to figure out how to display the result into the relevant UI areas in unity now!

Comment: Great!  mark this as answer :D Unity as in the gaming framework ?

Comment: this is the result now... Array ( [question] => What is 9x4? [answerA] => 16 [answerB] => 360 [answerC] => 32 [answerD] => 36 )   why is it printing the word ''Array?

Comment: Because we printed array using print_r() statement, just to show the content.

Comment: Thanks. sorry if im bugging you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at indentation, makes code much more plesant :)

```
<?php
$query = ("
    SELECT
        questiontable.questionId,
        questiontable.question,
        answertable.answerId,
        answertable.answer,
        answertable.questionId,
        questiontable.scoreValue
    FROM
        questiontable 
    INNER JOIN
        answertable on questiontable.questionId = answertable.questionId
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$data = [];
$data[] = null;

$keys = [
    'question',
    'answerA',
    'answerB',
    'answerC',
    'answerD',
];

$return = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ($data[0] !== $row['question']) {
        $data = [];
        $data[] = $row['question'];
    }

    $data[] = $row['answer'];

    if (count($data) === 5) {
        $dataAssociative = array_combine($keys, $data);
        $return[] = $dataAssociative;
    }
}

var_dump($return);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks peeps. Will try this as soon as I get home

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i have everything working with my php etc. i have it echoing the result as i want   heres the code...

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $output = array();

    $answer_array = array('answerA','answerB','answerC','answerD'); //loads answers into array

    $query = ("select * from questiontable ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1 ");//sql query to get questions
    $result =mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $output['question']=$row['question'];
        $query2 = ("select * from answerTable where questionId = '". ($row ['questionId'])."' order by rand()");//sql query to get answers for questions by questionId 
        $result2 =mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $i=0;
        $question=$row ['question'];
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $output[$answer_array[$i]]=$row2['answer'];
        $i++;
        $_POST = $output;
        }
                                          }
echo "</br> ";                                    
echo $_POST ['question'];
echo "</br> ";
echo $_POST['answerA'];
echo "</br>";
echo $_POST['answerB'];
echo "</br>";
echo $_POST['answerC'];
echo "</br> ";
echo $_POST['answerD'];
?>
```

now i need to store the results in unity so i can assign them to buttons etc. 
i have it pulling the details but unsure how to assign for example `$_POST['answerA];` to a variable in c#. 
this is my c# code...

```
public class qNaDisplay : MonoBehaviour {
public Text questionDisplayText, answerAText, answerBText, answerCText, answerDText;
public Text questMessage, answerMessage;

private string question, a, b, c, d;


// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    WWW questionURL = new WWW("http://localhost:8080/Project/PHP/questionRequest.php");
    question = questionDisplayText.text;
    a = answerAText.text;
    b = answerBText.text;
    c = answerCText.text;
    d = answerDText.text;
    StartCoroutine(qNaget(questionURL));
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

private  IEnumerator qNaget (WWW questionURL)
    {

```
    yield return  questionURL;
    Debug.Log(questionURL.text);
    if (questionURL.error != null)
    {
        print("There was an error getting the question " + questionURL.error);
    }
    else
    {
         Debug.Log (questionURL.text); // this is a GUIText that will display the scores in game.
    }
}
```

}